# Sequential conditional formatting

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I hope someone can help with this as my knowledge of excel is relatively limited.

I want to apply conditional formatting to a spreadsheet (see screenshot)

[image]

On each individual row, I want to show the figures in a different colour in columns H to L if they are less than the lower tolerance in column F or over the upper tolerance in column G. On each row, the value in columns F & G can change based on the product.

**Example** - formatting applied to cells H82 to L82 comes from information in cells F82 & G82, formatting for cells H83 to L83 comes from information in cells F83 & G83 and so on down the spreadsheet for as long as the spreadhseet is used (which will become thousands of entries)

I can successfully achieve this on individual rows through conditional formatting without any problem, however, I want to then apply the same criteria to the rest of the rows on the spreadsheet, using the cells in columns F & G on that particular row.

The problem I have is I can't find a way to copy that criteria to the rows below and the only way I can get this to work is by applying this row by row or copy/pasting to the rows below and editing the rule on every row individually.

Is there a quick way to do this or a formula I can apply that I can then just drag down on the spreadsheet and it would automatically update the cells in that formula as its dragged down? I'm sure for you guys its a simple enough thing, for me it's become a bit of a headache.

If there is a way, hopefully it can be explained in a way I'll be able to understand and apply it.

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set the conditional formatting to be based on a formula. Starting in cell H3 use this formula, then once it is typed in you can change the area it applies to.

```
=IF(OR(H3<$F3, H3>$G3), TRUE, FALSE)
```

The $ on F and G means that it will also reference those columns regardless of whether the cell you are formatting is in H, I, J, K or L.

You end up with something looking like this:

[image: sample output]

Comment: Thanks so much Ricky, you explained it really clearly and it works a treat, I can't thank you enough. Very much appreciated :)